# jQuery: effect of setting CSS property to empty string as opposed to setting it to none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've seen the following code:

```
$(this).css('border-color', '');
```

and wonder whether it is the same as:

```
$(this).css('border-color', 'none');
```

or whether in the first case the `border-color` CSS property is simply reset to its default value from the CSS stylesheet (and if not, then is there a way to reset the value to whatever is default in the stylesheet?). My concern is that I shouldn't have to change the jQuery JavaScript when I change the `border-color` in the stylesheet. Things should happen automatically.

Comment: Setting the property to an empty string works, but in older versions of Internet Explorer (up through IE9) it behaved badly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the css value to `none` is literally setting it to `none` in css. Setting it to an empty string removes the property from the `style` attribute on the tag.

```
<div style="border-color: none;"></div>
```

vs

```
<div style></div>
```

The reason you'd use `none` is if you want to overwrite an existing style that sets border-color to something. If you remove the style from the style attribute then it will fall back to an already defined style for border-color if it exists.

Comment: This is correct, but things don't work well in old versions of IE.